# Read QR code and Barcode with the same camera using javascript?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, barcode

I have to create a webapp, and the main point is reading QR code and Barcode with the same camera. So the camera should read both code, without changing anything. So far I've tried many options on github, but none of them can do the 2 thing with the same camera.

How can I do this using javascript? Or is there any working implementation? The app should work in chrome using android phones

Comment: The camera on a phone can already read both QR and barcode with apps...if you are trying to get the output in JavaScript then you need to include more info about the libraries you have tried and the exact specifications.

Comment: This should be possible with a little bit of research. Perhaps look at qr code reading libs and barcode. If you already have them build in, perhaps run them one after another with some timing.If one reader doesn't read anything then your app should switch to other reader. It's probably going to be slower than other readers

Comment: Which options did you try? Search for "format" or "symbologies" in the code, and set the values to 1D&QRCode. If the code can decode one format at a time, it should be easy to be modified to enable decoding two.